# Read a huge comma separated txt in c#

Tags: c#, csv, xls

Hello everyone i'am trying to find a great solution for a problem! I have a huge text file which contains 70 columns and few hundred lines! and the text is separated with commas. And the main thing is that afterwards I have to work with the data, because i have to import it into Excel.
I have tried the following:

```
FileStreamReader = File.OpenText(filepath);

        var query =
        from line in File.ReadLines(filepath)
        let empRecord = line.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None)
        //adatok osztályának példányositása
        select new adatok()
        {
            rendelt_mennyiseg = empRecord[0],
            egysegar = empRecord[1],
            szallitoi_nev = empRecord[2],
            szallitoi_cim = empRecord[3],
```

And basically the biggest problem is how to work with the data afterwards. How can I use a loop for the import into excel:

```
Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);

        xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

        //Loading datas shuld be here


        //Save

        xlWorkBook.SaveAs("elso.xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
        xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
        xlApp.Quit();
```

Comment: Sorry if this is too obvious, but have you checked that you can't just open it in Excel as a .csv file?

Comment: *which conatins 70 rows and few hundred lines* ? Does row and line is different from your point of view?

Comment: I think he meant 70 columns. I have suggested an edit.

Comment: This isn't a huge text file :)

Comment: So the CSV file, huge or not, turns out not to be relevant to the question at all. It is about importing a `List<adatok>` into Excel?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use set_Item method to set a cell value:

```
                xlWorkSheet .Cells.set_Item(rowIndex, <row index>, "your string");
```